# Apache on Mac - localhost server not found

Tags: apache

I did something I should not have while modifying the configuration of Apache on my Mac (10.8) and now I can't even load the page localhost.

What I did trying to solve the problem has been restore the original version of httpd.conf in /etc/apache2/ and restoring the config file hosts in /etc. I thought this would have been enough, but it is not.

Strange thing is that I can get the index.html to load by addressing either 127.0.0.1 or 0.0.0.0 . localhost does not answer!

Any ideas? Did i forget to restore a file?

Comment: Did you do `sudo /usr/sbin/apachectl restart` after you changed your `httpd.conf`?

Comment: Yes I did but nothing changes.

Comment: This is extremely very not good (TM). This problem has nothing to do with your Apache, you messed up your network routing. `localhost` should always point to `127.0.0.1`, and `0.0.0.0` isn't even a valid IP address. Are you sure you put back the origial `/etc/hosts`? Any other system file you've changed? Have you tried turning it off and back on again?

Comment: I am sure yes, it looks exactly like the one posted in Guy's answer. I also tried to reboot but no way.

Comment: Other thing that I tried and it is not working is the Virtual Hosts. Can you imagine a way I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you change your hosts file?

`/etc/hosts`

this should be set at it

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
fe80::1%lo0 localhost
```

Comment: Yes I restored to their original versions both the hosts file and the httpd.conf .